# R- create a superset from two vectors?

Tags: r, set

I am trying to add a vector that is a "super set" of two other lists in R. Right now, I don't think I've created the lists correctly but hopefully this can give you an example for what I am trying to do:

```
mygroups<-data.frame(number=c(1:5),members=c("a,b,c,d","e,f","b,c,d","e,f,g","c,d,a"))
mygroups2<- merge(mygroups, mygroups, by=NULL) %>% 
  filter(number.x!=number.y) %>%
  mutate(setofall = paste(members.x,members.y, sep=","))
mygroups2
```

Right now, "setofall" is not exactly a superset of 'members' - it's a straight up concatenation. "setofall", for example, for "a,b,c,d" and "b,c,d" is listed as "a,b,c,d,b,c,d" but "superset" should just be "a,b,c,d" for those two.

I have searched and found questions about [checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244949/check-if-a-vector-is-a-superset-of-another-vector-in-r) whether one vector is a superset of another, but not about finding the superset itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option using more `tidyverse` your **superset** is most often called a `union`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mygroups<-data.frame(number=c(1:5),members=c("a,b,c,d","e,f","b,c,d","e,f,g","c,d,a"))

mygroups2<- merge(mygroups, mygroups, by=NULL) %>%
   filter(number.x!=number.y)  %>%
   mutate(members.x = strsplit(members.x, ","),
          members.y = strsplit(members.y, ","))
mygroups2$setofall <- purrr::map2(mygroups2$members.x, mygroups2$members.y, ~ union(.x, .y))

mygroups2
#>    number.x  members.x number.y  members.y            setofall
#> 1         2       e, f        1 a, b, c, d    e, f, a, b, c, d
#> 2         3    b, c, d        1 a, b, c, d          b, c, d, a
#> 3         4    e, f, g        1 a, b, c, d e, f, g, a, b, c, d
#> 4         5    c, d, a        1 a, b, c, d          c, d, a, b
#> 5         1 a, b, c, d        2       e, f    a, b, c, d, e, f
#> 6         3    b, c, d        2       e, f       b, c, d, e, f
#> 7         4    e, f, g        2       e, f             e, f, g
#> 8         5    c, d, a        2       e, f       c, d, a, e, f
#> 9         1 a, b, c, d        3    b, c, d          a, b, c, d
#> 10        2       e, f        3    b, c, d       e, f, b, c, d
#> 11        4    e, f, g        3    b, c, d    e, f, g, b, c, d
#> 12        5    c, d, a        3    b, c, d          c, d, a, b
#> 13        1 a, b, c, d        4    e, f, g a, b, c, d, e, f, g
#> 14        2       e, f        4    e, f, g             e, f, g
#> 15        3    b, c, d        4    e, f, g    b, c, d, e, f, g
#> 16        5    c, d, a        4    e, f, g    c, d, a, e, f, g
#> 17        1 a, b, c, d        5    c, d, a          a, b, c, d
#> 18        2       e, f        5    c, d, a       e, f, c, d, a
#> 19        3    b, c, d        5    c, d, a          b, c, d, a
#> 20        4    e, f, g        5    c, d, a    e, f, g, c, d, a
```